# Conditional Query Expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have the below SQL in Access Query. But I need to add a condition to the Expression "Lasted".

```
SELECT ErrorLog.Reported_Date, ErrorLog.Details, ErrorLog.Started_At, ErrorLog.Ended_At,      ErrorLog.Project_Name, ([ended_at]-[started_at]) AS Lasted, ErrorLog.Not_Count_For_Pro_Time
FROM ErrorLog
GROUP BY ErrorLog.Reported_Date, ErrorLog.Details, ErrorLog.Started_At, ErrorLog.Ended_At,     ErrorLog.Project_Name, ([ended_at]-[started_at]), ErrorLog.Not_Count_For_Pro_Time;
```

This query is used as a Record Source for a report. As it stands now, the expression contains the value of " ([ended_at]-[started_at])". But I need to find a way to show 0 for "lasted", when "Not_Count_For_Pro_Time" is checked/True.

I have tried this code below, but it only shows the records where "Not_Count_for_Pro_Time" is false. I want the report to show all the records regardless if the "Not_Count_For_Pro_Time" is true or false, but the Expression "Lasted" should be adjusted as indicated earlier.

```
SELECT ErrorLog.Reported_Date, ErrorLog.Details, ErrorLog.Started_At, ErrorLog.Ended_At,     ErrorLog.Project_Name, ([ended_at]-[started_at]) AS Lasted, ErrorLog.Not_Count_For_Pro_Time
    FROM ErrorLog
    GROUP BY ErrorLog.Reported_Date, ErrorLog.Details, ErrorLog.Started_At, ErrorLog.Ended_At,     ErrorLog.Project_Name, ([ended_at]-[started_at]), ErrorLog.Not_Count_For_Pro_Time
    HAVING (((ErrorLog.Not_Count_For_Pro_Time)=False));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional logic:

```
IIF(ErrorLog.Not_Count_For_Pro_Time = 'true', 0, [ended_at]-[started_at]) AS Lasted,
```